# Refresh Google map with button click in v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to refresh my google map with a button click. There is marker with current location also.

Is there any Built-in refresh button in google map like zoom in & out?

Comment: what does "refresh the map" mean here? or more importantly why are you doing it?

Comment: As there is a marker in google map so, refreshing means here if the user change his position & click the refresh button then this will show him his current position in map with the marker .

Answer (score -1):

you can user below code for refresh google map. you need to put below function on-click of button.

```
public void RefreshMap() {
  map.getOverlays().clear();
  map.invalidate();
 ... create itemizedOverlay
 map.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
 map.invalidate();
 map.getController().animateTo(point);
}
```

For ItemizedOverlay you can find solution using below link.you can bind your marker by itemizedoverlay.

[Itemized Overlay](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/using-itemizedoverlay-to-add-marker-on.html)

Comment: This is old deprecated google maps v1 code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518212/why-getoverlays-is-undefined-for-the-mapview